# how can check if last three number are same jquery

Tags: jquery

I wondering how to check last three numbers if have same value, for example:

```
 html:
 <select>
 <option value="3000">3000</option>
 <option value="3245">3245</option>
 </select>

 JS 
 var selectedoption = "";     
 var lastdigits = $('select option').val().substring(1, 4);

 if(selectedOption != 000)) {
        lastdigits = selectedoption;
 }:
```

Is this right way?

Thanks for help,

Comment: last number? You mean option value or part of value?

Comment: part of vaue ..thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript's split and Set to check this.

Split the string into an array of characters

Now make a Set with that array. A Set contains unique elements, so any duplicates will be removed.

Check if there is only one element left in the Set, meaning the other two elements had the same value.

```
if(new Set(lastdigits.split('')).size === 1) {
    console.log('all were the same')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `split` value into chars and compare chars for occurences.

```js
// for each div
$("div").each(function() {
  // get value and turn into string for split
  const val = $(this).data('value').toString();
  
  const chars = val.split('');
  let numberOccurences = 0;
  
  // if bigger than 3 chars
  if(chars.length >= 3) {
    for(let i=chars.length-3; i<chars.length; i++) {
      // find occurences
      if(chars[i] === chars[i-1])
        numberOccurences++;

      // mark result
      if(numberOccurences == 2) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
        numberOccurences = 0;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-value="100333">
test A
</div>
<div data-value="1234">
test B
</div>
<div data-value="1444">
test C
</div>
```